# JPA Persist Entity with Foreign key value but don't want to explicit FIND for Foreign key Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to Persist an entity  `Book`  which has  `ManyToOne`  relationship with other entity  `Author` .

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "BOOK")
    public class Book {
        private int id;
        private Author author;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
     public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
}
```

So, When I want to save a Book entity, I need to FIND the Author entity using

```
Author aut = entityManager.find(Author.class, Id); 
book.setAuthor(aut); 
em.merge(book)
```

So, for finding of a Author I need to explicitly issue an SELECT query which I don't want to do. Is there any other way that, I can avoid explicit looking for foreign key but can persist the entity with Foreign key value?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [hibernate - how to save parent with detached child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130703/hibernate-how-to-save-parent-with-detached-child)

Answer (score 0):

Is it option for you to use JPQL? You can just use simple query

```
UPDATE Book b SET b.author=(SELECT a FROM Author a WHERE a.id=:author_id) WHERE b.id=:book_id
```

Another way to do this is following:

```
Author reference = entityManager.getReference(Author.class,authorId);
book.setAuthor(reference);
entityManager.merge(book);
```

A bit more info about [getReference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184186/1160959) method

This way select won't be issued.

Comment: entityManager.getReference(Author.class,authorId);

I tried with that approach and debug the code. It seems, when execute this line, a SELECT query issued to the Database. But, thats what I don't want. I want the SELECT for the Foreign key column would be implicit

Comment: @pijushcse isn't it what I wrote?

Comment: That serve the purpose. For saving the Book entity, a SELECT query need to execute for the Foreign key column. And, getReference() method issued a SELECT query.

Comment: It's very strange. Are you sure that it

Comment: Sorry, posted accidentally. It's very strange. Are you sure that it was called n this statement?

Comment: Yes, sir. I'm quite sure and spending a long time on that.

Comment: Is it possible that your class is final for example? Also may it be somehow linked to fact that you're using primitive int as id?

Comment: Class is not final. but Enitity Id field is a primitive (int) type. Is that a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. But it may be — hibernate works better with non-primitive types.

Comment: How do you check that the `select` is executed in the `getReference` method? Is it possible that you have a variable inspection window during debugging that triggers proxy initialization? Could you try logging something before and after the `getReference` method call without stopping on any break points to make sure that the `select` is executed in between?

Comment: it's easy: turn on hibernate logging in `persistence.xml`, place breakpoint on this statement, run all the program until hitting this breakpoint, clear console output and make one step in debugger. If then select is in your console - than it's actually executed on this statement. Another way is to make something like `============getting reference============` before and after statement and to see if hibernate makes db call between them.

Comment: @asm0dey Sure, I was asking the OP. :)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic sorry, thought it was OP, not other person.

Comment: I suppose that select is not issued when getReference() is called, but when the retrieved author is assigned to the book. Hibernate probably wants to check that the entity referenced by the foreign ley really exists in DB. This is not prescribed in JPA standard. It is possible that hibernate provides an option to turn this behavior off, but I'm not so into hibernate tweaking.

Comment: @OndrejM agreed, it's possible (a little strange though). Then OP has only option to use appropriate JPQL query.

Comment: No, Hibernate does not check whether the entity exists.