# Hibernate: insert data with foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following two tables in my database:

Calendar(id, name, user_id)

User(id, name, ...)

Each calendar is owned by one user, each user can have multiple calendars. Hence, there is a many-to-one relationship from Calendar to User. Now I'd like to insert a set of data into my Calendar table, my Calendar Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar")
public class Calendar {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User owner;
    ...
}
```

However, when I am inserting the data set, I do know the owner's id, but I don't have the corresponding `User` object. Do I have to retrieve the `User` object, set `owner` to it and then insert the data set?

This sounds a little inconvenient to me, is there a way to insert the data set using the `User` id as it would be stored in the database, as opposed to using a `User` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate - how to save parent with detached child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130703/hibernate-how-to-save-parent-with-detached-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get User proxy instance with the given owner's id (it is cheap operation). Then use this instance as owner value:

```
User dummy = hibernateTemplate.load(User.class, ID); //entityManager.getReference or session.load should do the trick too
calendar.setOwner(dummy);
hibernateTemplate.save(calendar)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that hibernate updates the User object as well, so all of its data apart from the id will be reset. Is there a way to deactivate this behaviour?

Comment: fixed an answer, give it a try :)

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but I guess there is no other way

Comment: at least it doesn't hit database :(

Comment: Is there another way to do that? I am facing the same situation. I don't want to retrieve the `user` each time to create a `calendar`.

Comment: @Keysersozem it is not hitting the database as Cootri mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a new `User` into your `Calendar`:

```
Calendar c = new Calendar();
c.setOwner(new User(id));
```